# Change library output directory when build json-c

Tags: c, cmake

I want to use json-c library in my project.

but in default, the library is installed in `/usr/local/lib` after I compile with `cmake; make; make install`
but I don't have root privilege, so "Permission denied" happened because I tried to modify `/usr/local/lib` directory.

so I want to change the LIBRARY DESTINATION to a directory that I can modify.

How can I do it? I've thought I have to change `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` variable in CMakeLists.txt. But I couldn't find the definition of the variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR`.

This is the json-c github url : https://github.com/json-c/json-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no need to modify the files, just change the install destination.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/users/HyeonseopJeong/c-json ...
```

The default `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is `/usr/local`, so all other paths will be in `/usr/local/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html)